# The dimension of formal series modulo $\sin(x)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have reasons to think that the dimension over $\mathbb{C}$ of  $\mathbb{C} \{t\}$, the ring of (convergent) formal series modulo the ideal generated by $\sin(t)$, has finite dimension, how can I show this (or show that it is infinite dimensional).

The intuition comes from the identity $\sin(t)^2 + \cos(t)^2 = 1$, in some sense this "says" that $t = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ring $A = \mathbb{C}[[t]]$ is local with maximal ideal $(t)$. Thus for any $f = a + tg$ with $a\in \mathbb{C}$ and $g\in A$, we have
\begin{align*}
f = a + \left(\frac{\sin t}{t}\right)^{-1}g \sin t.
\end{align*}
It follows that $A/(\sin t)$ is a $1$-dimensional vector space.

Comment: We can also skip to the chase and use the fact that $t = (\sin t/t)^{-1}\sin t$ to conclude that $(\sin t) = (t)$. Since $(t)$ is maximal, $A/(t)$ is a field; that is (since we're working over $\mathbb{C}$), it has dimension $1$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.